# Store query results into object

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I try to read sql table and load all into a variable

Code:

```
  String query2 = "";
    query2 = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Seguridad.UsuarioPerfil WHERE UsuarioID = {0}", UsuarioID);
                SQLService sqlservice2 = new SQLService();
                DataTable reader2 = sqlservice.Leer(query2);
```

I want to store all data into a variable  `var tmpPerfiles`  as object.

I can do something like:

```
var tmpPerfiles ="";
 foreach (DataRow row in reader.Rows)
                {
                    tmpPerfiles = row["UsuarioId"].ToString();
                    tmpPerfiles = row["PerfilId"].ToString();
                }
```

But I can´t call tmpPerfiles two times. How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: I can't answer your question but in fact I can give you a good hint.
Plz do not use this kind of sql query creation. You have a highly risk of sql injection. See msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first up: STOP!  Do not EVER write SQL queries like this.  SQL Injection Attack is still the #1 cause of security breaches and vulnerabilities (per OWASP), and it's exclusively caused by people writing SQL statements like this.

Never ever write SQL statements like:

```
statement = "SELECT something from sometable where " + someVar ...
```

... because all it takes is for that 'somevar' to have an apostrophe and some malicious hacking code, and you're granting an external entity access to your database.  Don't even do it if you're not expecting the field to be user-provided or such - it's a bad habit, and it leads to horrendous security faults.

Instead, you should always use one of the following:

- Stored Procedures with parameterized inputs.  Aka, dbo.usp_FindUser,
  which accepts @userName, and the proc has WHERE name = @userName
- Parameterized Sql Command.  Aka, creating a SqlCommand with "Select *
  from something from someTable where userName = @userName", and then
  adding a parameter to the SqlCommand of userName, and a value of what
  user you're looking for.

Okay, all that said?

Keep in mind, a variable can contain a grouping of things.  Generally, if you're looking to contain a table within a single variable?  It'll typically look something like:

```
string x, int y, string z - fields within the Database
Class dataRecord - a class, which contains string x, int y, string z.
List<dataRecord> - a list of instances of a dataRecord class
```

... make sense?  You've got one variable per column, which you group into a class.  One instance of the class represents one data row.  And then a List<> of that class represents multiple rows of that table (or just the whole table itself.)

Usually, code that follows SRP (but that doesn't use EntityFramework) will look something like:

```
List<myFancyClass> tableEntries = new List<myFancyClass>();
foreach (DataRow dr in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    myFancyClass line = new myFancyClass(dr); // constructor that takes in a DataRow
    tableEntries.Add(line);
}
```

... at that point, the table is stored in the tableEntries variable.

Answer (score 1):

e.g.
use a dto for storing it into a list

```
private class TmpDto {
    string UsuarioId { get; set;}
    string PerfilId { get; set;}
}

var Ilist<TmpDto> list = new List<TmpDto>();
foreach (DataRow row in reader.Rows)
{
    var dto = new TmpDto();
    dto.UsuarioId = row["UsuarioId"].ToString();
    dto.UsuarioId = row["PerfilId"].ToString();
    list.Add(dto);
}
```

so you have several objects stored within a list

Comment: This is a great example of the "data/domain object" I referenced in my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EntityFramework, this is really easy.  After setting up a class for the object (containing all fields), just use linq to get the object.

```
var myData = UsuarioPerfil.Where(e => e.UsuarioID == UsuarioID).FirstorDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get values from a database and put them into *something*, then I think the introduction of a datatable is overkill.  While the implementation is easy enough, it adds overhead.  I'd opt to use a `DbDataReader` instead.

This is an example of extracting a single field, and then just adding it to a list.

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();

String query2 = "SELECT PerfilId FROM Seguridad.UsuarioPerfil WHERE UsuarioID = @USARIO";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@USARIO", SqlDbType.VarChar));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = UsuarioID;

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    results.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}

reader.Close();
```

You referenced two fields, but since `UsuarioID` was defined in the where clause, it didn't seem necessary to pull it back.

Also, as @DotNetDev mentioned, don't use literals...  the use of parameters is not only SQL-Injection safe, but it's more scalable and actually friendlier to the database (compile-once, execute many).

Finally, if you want to pull back multiple fields, create a data (domain) object, and make your results a list of that object.  If you need an example, feel free to ask.